# The dash home is very slow (ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: unity, 13.04, unity-dash

So I just installed Ubuntu 13.04 32bit (alongside windows 7), everything fine in the installation, I loged in and everything fine, until I opened the dash home, it was absurdly slow, so slow that the computer froze and i hat to restart it.
So I looked for a solution on internet and I installed "unity tweak tool" and disabled blur on the dash home. That helped A LOT, but it's still quite slow (mostly while typing, but everything in general is slow) but at least it doesn't freeze anymore (at least not everytime I open it, since i did that blur thing it just froze once) but as I said, it's still quite slow and this is very annoying, is there a solution? here is my computer info if it helps:

RAM: 2GB
Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 4200+ × 2 
Graphics (drivers): Gallium 0.4 on NV46

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the Nouveau driver for the graphics card which probably doesn't support sufficient 3D acceleration for Unity.  If you are able to install the proprietary nVidia drivers, it would certainly improve performance.

Open System Settings and select Software and Updates.  There is an Additional Drivers tab which will show you if any alternative drivers are available.

You can also run the following command which will show you whether your current driver supports Unity 3D:

```
/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
```

Check the lines that say "Not blacklisted" and "Unity 3D supported"

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks!  The processor is an AMD but the video card appears to be nVidia.  Gallium is the name of the renderer for the Nouveua drivers and NV46 is (I believe) a model number for an nVidia card.

Comment: Whops! My bad. I don't know what the hell was I thinking! I'll delete my comment.